# Free 2D char array

Tags: c, arrays, memory, free

I need to free an array of pointers.  So I have set up a simple error prone example of what I am trying to do.

```
int main() {

    char ** strings = malloc(2);
    strings[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*4);
    strings[1] = malloc(sizeof(char)*4);

    strings[0] = "ABCD";
    strings[1] = "EFGH";

    free(strings[1]);
}
```

I believe I need to free the pointers in reverse order so I started with index one.
However I get this error:

`free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400d49 ***`

Freeing like `free(strings);` clears index zero, however calling it again throws the error:

`double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000008e5010 ***`

What is the correct way to wipe out this pointer array?  Or if there is something wrong with how I created the array, please let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
strings[0] = "ABCD"
```

replaces the pointer to allocated memory with a pointer to the string literal `"ABCD"`.  You didn't allocate memory for this so can't free it.

Use

```
strcpy(strings[0], "ABCD");
```

to copy into the memory you allocated.

Note that you'll still have another couple of problems here.  First, you need to allocate space for two pointers in your `strings` array - you currently only allocate 2 bytes.  Second, `"ABCD"` requires 5 bytes of storage (the 5th byte is for the nul terminator).  You therefore either need to allocate 5 bytes for each array or, better, combine allocation and string copying using [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) (a Posix rather than C standard function)

```
char ** strings = malloc(2 * sizeof(*strings));
strings[0] = strdup("ABCD");
strings[1] = strdup("EFGH");
```

Comment: @user3121023 Thanks.  I'd copied this from the question without noticing the further bug.  Now corrected.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the null terminator, and showing me how to correctly allocate memory to the array, I understand how that works now. Also I see how to avoid this problem by copying the value.  However, I do not understand why I need to do that.  Are you saying that `"ABCD"` is currently a static constant, so effectively read only?

Comment: @Flosculus The assignment in `strings[0] = "ABCD";` does not copy the contents of one string into another; it merely changes a pointer to point to a different address.  Content inside quotes is called a string literal.  The string this points to is available for the duration of the program.  It may but isn't guaranteed to be read only.  The best way to think about memory management is that each call to `malloc` must have exactly one matching call to `free`.  You didn't `malloc` `"ABCD"` so cannot later `free` it.

Comment: Ah, so the memory I allocated with `strings[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*4);` would have been leaked right?

Answer (score 2):

```
int main() {
    char ** strings = malloc(sizeof(char*)*2);
    strings[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
    strings[1] = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);

    strcpy(strings[0], "ABCD");
    strcpy(strings[1], "EFGH");

    free(strings[0]);
    free(strings[1]);
    free(strings);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code `strings[0] = "ABCD";` is not doing what you expect.

Instead of copying the bytes to the allocated array you get a memory leak. You re-assign `strings[0]` to point to string literal equal to `"ABCD"`(thus the allocated array is leaked). That is why calling `free` on `strings[1]` fails. What you need to do is use strcpy:

```
strcpy(strings[0], "ABCD");
strcpy(strings[0], "EFGH");
```